# How to Mock a Static function with WebMvcTest in Springboot

Tags: mockito, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

Is there any functionality within the @WebMvcTest annotation that can be used to test static functions of a class?

Comment: yes, you can. See https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods

Comment: @Kai-ShengYang your response does not help, because the issue is: `MockedStatic` is thread-local. This means, that a class has usually been loaded beforehand and depending on what the questioneer wants, **it might not be possible** with `Mockito#mockStatic`. I am currently facing the same issue with `NetworkInterface`. I can mock static methods there, but `@ContextConfiguration` has already run.

Answer (score 0):

Since I believe I found it out (and it's lacking in the baeldung-tutorial linked), here's an example (I don't use `@WebMvcTest` currently, I am testing a configuration object):

***(see below for an explanation)***

```java
(imports omitted in favor of brevity)

@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ServerObjectConfiguration.class)
class ServerObjectConfigurationTest {

    // 192.168.178.82
    private static final byte[] EXAMPLE_IP_V4 = {-64, -88, -78, 82};
    // 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
    private static final byte[] EXAMPLE_IP_V6 = {32, 1, 13, -72, -123, -93, 0, 0, 0, 0, -118, 46, 3, 112, 115, 52};
    private static final byte[] EXAMPLE_MAC_ADDRESS = {-68, -48, 116, 9, -47, 11};
    private static final MockedStatic<NetworkInterface> mockedNetworkInterface = Mockito.mockStatic(NetworkInterface.class);
    private static final MockedStatic<InetAddress> mockedInetAddress = Mockito.mockStatic(InetAddress.class);

    @Autowired
    private ServerObjectConfiguration serverObjectConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    private Server server;

    @SneakyThrows
    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() {
        // This is SPARTAAA... or rather: crazy, because everything java.net seems to smell of bad design decisions
        InetAddress ipV4InetAddress = mock(InetAddress.class);
        when(ipV4InetAddress.getAddress())
                .thenReturn(EXAMPLE_IP_V4);
        when(ipV4InetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress())
                .thenReturn(true);

        InetAddress ipV6InetAddress = mock(InetAddress.class);
        when(ipV6InetAddress.getAddress())
                .thenReturn(EXAMPLE_IP_V6);
        when(ipV6InetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress())
                .thenReturn(true);

        InterfaceAddress ipV4InterfaceAddress = mock(InterfaceAddress.class);
        when(ipV4InterfaceAddress.getAddress())
                .thenReturn(ipV4InetAddress);

        InterfaceAddress ipV6InterfaceAddress = mock(InterfaceAddress.class);
        when(ipV6InterfaceAddress.getAddress())
                .thenReturn(ipV6InetAddress);

        NetworkInterface networkInterface = mock(NetworkInterface.class);
        when(networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses())
                .thenReturn(List.of(ipV4InterfaceAddress, ipV6InterfaceAddress));
        when(networkInterface.getHardwareAddress())
                .thenReturn(EXAMPLE_MAC_ADDRESS);

        mockedInetAddress.when(() -> InetAddress.getByAddress(EXAMPLE_IP_V4))
                .thenReturn(ipV4InetAddress);
        mockedInetAddress.when(() -> InetAddress.getByAddress(EXAMPLE_IP_V6))
                .thenReturn(ipV6InetAddress);

        mockedNetworkInterface.when(() -> NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ipV4InetAddress))
                .thenReturn(networkInterface);
        mockedNetworkInterface.when(() -> NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ipV6InetAddress))
                .thenReturn(networkInterface);
        mockedNetworkInterface.when(NetworkInterface::networkInterfaces)
                .thenReturn(Stream.of(networkInterface));
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void tearDown() {
        mockedInetAddress.close();
        mockedNetworkInterface.close();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void test_serverObjectIsConfiguredAsExpected() {
        // the bean uses NetworkInterface to get the IP-addresses and MAC-address 
        assertThat(server.getMacAddresses()).containsOnly(EXAMPLE_MAC_ADDRESS);
        assertThat(server.getIpAddresses()).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(EXAMPLE_IP_V4, EXAMPLE_IP_V6);
    }
}
```

To mock a static method in a way, that Spring Boot uses it during Bean initialization / context creation, you **have to** do it in a `@BeforeAll` (JUnit5) annotated method, which is static. The reason is, that you want to mock the static method as early in your test as you can.

I tried to use a thread-local `Mockito#mockStatic` call, but since my bean is getting initialized before the test even starts, my attempt at mocking the relevant static methods was too late.

This approach definitely works and the `Server`-bean, that contains the IP-addresses and the MAC-address, receives the values I am expecting it to.